# Reliable IPC With Shell Scripts

Tags: shell, unix

Okay, so I have two shell scripts, a server and a client, where the server is always run as root, and the clients can be run as standard users in order to communicate with the server.

The method I've chosen to do this is with a world-accessible directory containing named pipes (fifos), one of which is world-writable (to enable initial connection requests) and the others are created per-user and writable only by them (allowing my server script to know who sent a message).

This seems to work fine but it feels like it may be over-engineered or missing a more suitable alternative. It also lacks any means of determining whether the server is currently running, besides searching for its name in the output of `ps`. This is somewhat problematic as it means that writing to the connection fifo will hang if the server script isn't available to read from it.

Are there better ways to do something like this for a shell script? Of course I know could use an actual program to get access to more capabilities, but this is really just intended to provide secure access to a root service for non-root users (i.e - it's a wrapper for something else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Unix domain sockets](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) instead of fifos.  Domain sockets can be created with `nc -lU /path/to/wherever` and connected to with `nc -U /path/to/wherever`.  This creates a persistent object in the filesystem (like a fifo, but different).  The server should be able to maintain multiple simultaneous connections over the same socket.

If you're willing to write in C (or some other "real" programming language), it's also possible to pass credentials over Unix domain sockets, unlike fifos.  This makes it possible for the server to authenticate its clients without needing to rely on filesystem permissions or other indirect means.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any widely-supported interface for doing this in a shell script.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like it might be a cleaner way to do what I'm currently doing, is it possible to send replies from the server in this method? I forgot to mention I'm currently having to use another fifo for output, which works, but requires some collision resolution if several processes are trying to connect at the same time (since they'll consume each other's messages).

Comment: Sockets are generally bidirectional, once a connection is established.  `nc` will (by default) read from stdin and write to stdout.  Please note that domain sockets share the socket interface with TCP and UDP.  For example, if the server is not listening when the client tries to connect, the client errors out rather than blocking.  If the server tries to bind to a socket file that already exists, it gets `EADDRINUSE`.  And so on.

Comment: Seems I might still need a named pipe on the server-side for bidirectional usage then, but otherwise this does some somewhat more useful. I just wanted to add also that it seems that the `nc -klU foo` form seems to be needed to handle multiple connections; this still blocks until the first connection closes, but other connections are queued up. With `nc -lU foo` only the first connection gets handled, and others seem to just be ignored, but no error is produced (client still appear to connect).